# Exportar de datagridview a excel ciertas columnas

Tags: c#, datagrid

Tengo una duda.

Tengo este código para el llenado de un datagridview, el cual obtiene los datos de un documento excel.

```
string constr = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;");

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
//Hacer los comandos

OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [MPS 
Sheet$A16:AP]", con);


con.Open();

//Hacer los adapters
OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);

//hacer los datatables
DataTable data = new DataTable();



ds.Tables.Add(data);
sda.Fill(data);
//Hacer las tablas
dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
//dataGridView7.DataSource = fecha;
con.Close();
```

Lo que quiero hacer ahora, es obtener solo tres columnas de las que tiene este datagridview, para colocarlos en otro nuevo datagridview.

Mi duda es ¿Se puede hacer? y si se puede ¿Como se haría?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, sí es posible. Solo hay que especificar las columnas que necesitas. Este es un ejemplo que me brindo un compañero, espero te sirva.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Data;   


 namespace BDPROG_CSharp
 {
     class classExcel
     {
         public int columnas;
         DataTable dt;
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;           

         public classExcel(int columnas, DataTable dt)
         {
             this.columnas = columnas;
             this.dt = new DataTable();
             this.dt = dt;
         }
         public void crearexcel()
         {

             oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
             oXL.Visible = true;
             //Creamos un nuevo libro de Excel
             oXL.Workbooks.Add();
             oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oXL.ActiveSheet;
             //Le asignamos a la hoja 1 el nombre de "Datos"
             oSheet.Name = "Datos";
             //Pegamos el contenido
             oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, 1], oSheet.Cells[1, 1]).Select();
             oXL.ActiveCell.PasteSpecial();
             oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, 1], oSheet.Cells[1, 1]).EntireColumn.Delete();

             ////Creamos los encabezados                                     
             for (int z = 0; z <= columnas; z++)
             {
                 oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1] = Convert.ToString(dt.Columns[z].ColumnName);

                 //  oSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").Font.Bold = true;
                 oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1], oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1]).Font.ColorIndex = 2;
                 oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1], oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1]).Interior.ColorIndex = 5;
                 oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1], oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1]).Font.Bold = true;
                 oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1], oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1]).Font.Italic = true;
                 oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1], oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1]).VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
                 // oRng = (oSheet.Cells[1, z], oSheet.Cells[1, z]);
                 oRng = oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1], oSheet.Cells[1, z + 1]);
                 oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

             }






         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: pero esto es para obtener el rango desde el documento excel ¿no?, lo que yo necesito es a partir del datagridview que ya llené con anterioridad,llenar otro datagridview con solo ciertas columnas del primero

Comment: Si verificas a partir del for, solo especificas las columnas que quieres exportar.

Comment: Gracias. Ya me funcionó